# Удаление и добавление элемента React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть state:

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Objects: {
                name: '',
                type: '',
                massVariant: [
                    {
                        form: '1',
                        photoUpload: '1',
                        count: '1',
                        countMass: '1',
                    },
                    {
                        form: '2',
                        photoUpload: '2',
                        count: '2',
                        countMass: '2',
                    }
                ]
            },
        }
    }
```

Есть две кнопки, кликая по одной надо добавлять новый объект с пустыми значениями в massVariant, а кликая по другой удалять.

Я написал эти функции, но почему то ни не работают.

Удаление:

```js
clickDelete = (index) => {
    let newMass = [...this.state.Objects.massVariant];
    newMass.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({
        massVariant: newMass
    })
}
```

Добавление:

```js
addRowVar = () => {
    const Objects= [ ...this.state.Objects]
    const element = {
        form: '',
        photoUpload: '',
        count: '',
        countMass: 'tset1'
    }
    const newArray = [ ...Objects.massVariant, element ];
    this.setState({ Objects: newArray });
}
```

Где я ошибся?

Comment: 1) У вас в state нет свойства massVariant; 2) Objects в state не массив

Comment: 1. massVariant это массив у меня с объектами.
2. Objects это объект. Так и должно быть

Comment: у вас как стейт выглядит? Как `{Objects: {....}}`? Или как объект с ключами `name, type, ...`? Просто вы добавляете `massVariant` в рутовый объект, а не в `Objects`, покажите как вы стейт инициализируете

Comment: Поправил стейт в вопросе.

Comment: Читайте еще раз первый комментарий, скорее всего "промежуточное" свойство Objects вам вообще не нужно, кладите всё сразу в state, тогда удаление заработает сразу, вставку поправить тоже будет проще

Comment: У меня помимо Objects в стейте еще есть объекты и масивы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не правильно обновляете стейт

`this.setState({ Objects: newArray });` полностью перезапишет ключ `Objects`, сделав его массивом

Нужно что-то вроде этого:

```
addRowVar = () => {
    const Objects = { ...this.state.Objects } // это объект, не массив!
    const element = {
        form: '',
        photoUpload: '',
        count: '',
        countMass: 'tset1'
    }

    this.setState({ Objects: {
        ...Objects,
        massVariant: [ ...Objects.massVariant, element ] // а вот это массив
    }});
}
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное. Извиняйте за глупые вопросы. Когда понимаешь, что было не так, сам поражаешься на сколько глуп был вопрос.